# Cache busting with grunt and JSTL c:url

Tags: node.js

I have a Java/Spring webapp and I'm trying to use `grunt-cache-bust` to cache bust my resource files (js, css) but this package doesn't seem like it is able to detect my resources and cache bust them.  Does anyone know of another package that can do this while still allowing me to retain the use of JSTL's c:url?

I had referential problems loading resources in my site so I'm not open to removing c:url unless there's truly a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grunt-cache-bust` version 1.3.0 supports `c:url value="someresource.js"` inside a JS/CSS import.  In the project I was working on discovered the reason why it wasn't working (which led to posting the question), the href or src attributes used single quotes instead of double quotes and these were not picked up by the cache bust module.

I changed this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<c:url value='/CSS/dialogs/dialog.css'/>'/>`

to this and it worked:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/CSS/dialogs/dialog.css"/>"/>`